# XCode 7.0.1, link failing during Archive even with BitCode = NO for AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, xcode7, bitcode

I know there are a couple of other questions about this out there, but they are not solving this problem.

Pre XCODE 7.x project, upgraded to XCODE 7.0.1

Getting the following error when linking

```
ld: '[deleted]/ThridParty/AmazonMobileAnalytics/AWSCore.framework/AWSCore(AWSCredentialsProvider.o)' does not contain bitcode. 
You must rebuild it with bitcode enabled (Xcode setting ENABLE_BITCODE), 
obtain an updated library from the vendor, or disable bitcode for this target. for architecture armv7
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Even with build settings Enable Bitcode set to NO.

This is happening during ARCHIVE, but works fine for sim builds.

Comment: Turns out this was an issue with the xcodebuild verb.  It was pointing to an incorrect version of XCode.  The BITCODE = NO does work.